# MS SQL SERVER MIGRATION TO MY SQL WIZARD Error

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

So I have been using the Migration Wizard in MySQL to Migrate tables and databases and for the longest time it has been working fine. Recently I tried migrating tables or databases using the migration wizard and now I am getting errors and it is not allowing me to migrate anymore and it is happening to all my tables even the ones I was able to migrate before. I am getting the following error when migrating. Can anyone help me with this?

> 10:49:42 [WRN][      copytable]: 6 characters could not be converted
>   to UTF-8 from column Name during copy
>
> 10:49:42 [WRN][      copytable]: 8 characters could not be converted
>   to UTF-8 from column Name during copy
>
> 10:49:42 [WRN][      copytable]: 16 characters could not be converted
>   to UTF-8 from column Name during copy

Sometimes I also get this error a packetsize error as well. Saying that it is to large and when I checked my tables they are all in the right size.

Any ideas what has changed or happened on why the migration wizead is preventing me to make move tables from MS SQL to MySQL?